# Firebase - Prevent race condition on user registration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase/Next.js application that I'm working on, deployed through Firebase hosting.

In this application, I am trying to implement a feature related to user registration. When a user registers an account, the user is given a document containing their data. One of my fields in the document is the account number. For this specific application, I would like the account number to increment by 1 for each account, in order of creation. For example, the first user would have account number 1, and the next would have 2, and so on.

The way I would normally go to implement something like this would be to create a `Next.js` API route. The API would verify the user's token, read the number of existing users from Firestone, and finally create a document for the user.

While this would work if the API was only ever being used by one user, there would be a race condition if multiple users called the API at the same time. Considering the following order of events.

```
- Server has 3 users
Alice : Reads the number of current users (3)
Bob : Reads the number of current users (3)
Bob : Creates user #4
Alice : Creates user #4
- Server has 5 users, Alice and Bob are both user #4
```

What it seems like I need to do is have a way of queuing these requests, such as that each API calls to add a request to the queue, which is resolved once it is reached. In practice, I'm not sure what implementing something like that would look like.

An easy way to do this would be to run a cloud function every second, which reads from the queue, creates the user, and then removes the request from the queue. While this would work it would be wasteful and inefficient.

Is there a way to do something like this in Firebase efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that I see would be to create a counter field inside a document in Firestore that can be incremented on each user creation. The steps for achieving that would be:

1. Before creating a user in Firebase, [deploy and register a blocking function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions#deploy_and_register_a_blocking_function).

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {
  const count = admin.firestore().collection('users').count();
});
```

As you can see, to count the users I have used the [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) function.

2. [As soon as the user is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation), you can create another function that should perform two Firestore operations. One is to write user data to Firestore using the value of the count and one is to increment the value of the counter.

```
exports.writeDataToFirestore = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // Code to write user data and update the counter.
});
```

Since you perform two operations you can perform them in a [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). Please note that a batch operation completes atomically. Besides that, when you increment the counter, there is no need for a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions), you can simply [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) the value. The latter operation is also atomic, so there is no way you can have two users with the same count. Besides that, there is also no need to run a cloud function every second.

Comment: Hey Julian. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have not had a chance to try it yet, but I will update you when I have.

Comment: Ok Julian, give it a try and tell me if it works.